# Metro : Getting strings from Resources with globalization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro, translation

I am designing a media player for the Windows Store and I am using a Resources.resw file to store all the strings in English (en-GB) and other .xlf files to store translations in several other languages.
I am using `x:Uid="*something*"` in the XAML code to access the strings. For example I have the next AppBarButton :

```
 <AppBarButton Icon="Play" 
               x:Uid="Play" 
               Label="Play" 
               Click="btnPlayPause_Click" 
               Name="PlayPauseAppBarButton"/>
```

Displaying the text in any language I tried worked perfectly. The only problem is that my "PlayPauseAppBarButton" is a double purpose button :
- when there is nothing playing the  the Icon is "Play" and Label is "Play"
- when there is something playing right now the Icon is "Pause" and Label **should be** "Pause"

Changing the Icon from code was very simple :

```
PlayPauseAppBarButton.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Pause);
```

The problem remains to change the Label accordingly.
I have already tried :

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
PlayPauseAppBarButton.Label = loader.GetString("Pause.Label");
```

There are not errors, the resource "Pause.Label" is recognised, but when the program is running it displays "Play" (because of the initial XAML) and when it has to change the Label, it displays nothing. After debug, I observed that loader.GetString("Pause.Label") return a "" value (no text).

So how can I resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to access a resource string labeled with "Pause.Label" via C# you can call

```
loader.GetString("Pause/Label");
```

You could also create a custom Control with appropriate Visual States (e.g. "Paused" / "Playing") that reveal the necessary buttons and labels (including xaml loaded label-content via x:uid)

greetings